read slack messages using python
I need to read historic messages from a Slack channel using python. I followed How read slack channel messages using python-slackclient and have:
import os
import slack

client = slack.WebClient(token="xoxb-xxx")
channel = "C06RU24ST8S"
# attempt 1
result = client.conversations_history(channel=channel)
# attemp2
history = client.api_call(api_method='conversations.history',data={'channel':channel})

but each attempt results in error: channel not found.
I obtained the channelID from here:

Am pretty confident that the bot has access rights, as it sends messages to this channel currently
Any suggestions how to fix this so I can read historic messages
